# How to determine current app in Lightning mode from Apex

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-experience, app

I'm trying to determine the current app in Lightning mode from Apex.

In Salesforce Classic, I was able to use the `isSelected()` of [`DescribeTabSetResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_schema_describetabsetresult.htm) to determine the title of the current app. Upon switching to Lightning however, the current app (or the app that `isSelected`) remains the last app selected while in Salesforce Classic view.

Is there a function in Apex that will determine the current app while in Lightning?

Thanks!